# Spring boot tries to render login processing url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

Hello guys im trying to make custom login form with spring boot 2 and thymeleaf 3 , application have 2 security config one for mobile app users and other one for restaurants which is an web application.Im implementing custom login form for restaurant side but when login form is submitted spring tries to find localhost:8080/{loginprocessingurl} and this leads to 404 error.
Here are my form , controllers and security config below :

```
@Configuration
    @Order(2)   // no order means order of config value is last
    public static class RestaurantSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
            http.csrf().and()
            .antMatcher("/restaurant/**")  //antmatcher tekil şekilde urlleri farklı configler için gruplamada kullanılır
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/assets/**", "/webjars/**","/static/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("RESTAURANT")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/restaurant/reslogin")
                .failureUrl("/restaurant/login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/restaurant/tables",true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/restaurant/logout")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            ;
        }
```

Controllers:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/restaurant")
public class RestaurantController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getlogin(Model model) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("login");
        return mav;
    }
```

and my login form:

```
  <form class="mt-5" name="f" th:action="@{/restaurant/reslogin}" method="post">
              <!-- <div th:if="${loginError}">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        Invalid username or password.
                    </div>
                </div> -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Restoran Kullanıcı Adı</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Parola</label>
                <input type="password"  class="form-control" id="password" name="password"  placeholder="Parola">
              </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Giriş</button>

            </form>
```

And i saw that thymeleaf does not inject a csrf token input when i looked to source page.
I use thymeleaf extras springsecurity version 3.0.4, if ı write csrf input maually in the form

```
<input
  type="hidden"
  th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
  th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

, it yields to me this error : EL1007E: Property or field 'parameterName' cannot be found on null
   The thing is i know spring should handle the login processing url on the back side and do the authentication ( i made the implementation of UserDetailsService and override WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter's configureGlobal method correctly how i know because mobile app requests work well(the other @Configuration class)) but instead redirect me on success url , it tries to render that login processing url.
   The other thing when i dont use custom login processing url instead use the default /login for posting login form , it says 405 method not allowed, but all the other examples that i tried on the web works like this, and even in Begining Spring Boot 2 book by K.Siva Prasad Reddy, i did the form login ex. which written like i told above, works like charm ! Every dependency versions are the same !
   I've been dealing with this 2 days and searched everywhere but couldn't find a solution so every idea and suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue and it was caused by not having same RequestMatcher in other config class, my bad.

```
http
    .antMatcher("/user/**")
```

So if any fellow spring boot lovers encounter the same issue , be sure that you mapped 2 configuration for separate urls.